# Am I doing something wrong with the Bisect tool?

Tags: tools, bisect

I am trying to cut (bisect) an imported mesh, but I think I am doing something wrong or the mesh is just broken.
Video:
https://youtu.be/mqQdibQdQhA

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: does it work if you select all in Edit mode?

Comment: no. as showed in the video, it doesn't. it must be a mesh error, but how would i fix it?

Comment: yes sorry, I didn't realize, maybe share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/4c392152f38d43f784c8337d1cd66e7d sorry for late replies

Comment: Edit: so it looks like if you merge the vertices it will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have split faces, select all in *Edit* mode and merge by distance, with enough *Merge Distance* in the *Operator* box, then use the bisect tool, it will work fine.

Comment: i cannot seem to find "merge by distance" in the merge menu.

Comment: Select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance (bottom of the pop-up window)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iXaltGq

Comment: yes, choose By Distance  ;)

Comment: oh oof, and then, what properties?

Comment: once you've clicked on the By Distance option, there's the Operator box on the bottom left of your 3D view, increase the Merge Distance enough so that it merges the vertices, you have overlapping faces and split faces for the moment, the Bisect tool won't work correctly